# How to push only the specific changeset in git after new branch creation?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have made four commits in the master branch and then created a new branch called **b1** and then made a 5th commit (I mean first commit of the newly created branch) and checked the out coming changes of **b1** but it shows all the changesets right from origin (i.e) *1st-5th* changesets. Does any one know why it  is showing all the changesets right from the beginning instead of the specific changesets?

Note:
If I made the 6th commit only that specific changeset is shown in the outcoming changesets.

**Flow Map:** 

|    |
|    |
|    6
|    |
|   5
|   /
|  / ----> b1 (new branch)
| /
4
|
3
|
2
|
1  ----> master

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "checked the out coming changes"? What command did you use?

Comment: What do you mean with 'it shows all the changesets'? Again, what command?

Comment: @DavidDeutsch:  "checked the out coming changes" means the changes that are to be pushed server.

Comment: @Joost:  'it shows all the changesets' means after my new branch creation when I checked what are changesets going to pushed.

Cmd:
!git fetch && git log FETCH_HEAD..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A branch consists of the commit the branch head points to, and *all* ancestors of that commit. Therefore, commits 1, 2, 3, and 4 are indeed in the b1 branch. So when you push b1, those commits get pushed as well.